Why is the struct not updated in my contract?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

/**
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }

    function _contextSuffixLength() internal view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * The initial owner is set to the address provided by the deployer. This can
 * later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    /**
     * @dev The caller account is not authorized to perform an operation.
     */
    error OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(address account);

    /**
     * @dev The owner is not a valid owner account. (eg. `address(0)`)
     */
    error OwnableInvalidOwner(address owner);

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the address provided by the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor(address initialOwner) {
        if (initialOwner == address(0)) {
            revert OwnableInvalidOwner(address(0));
        }
        _transferOwnership(initialOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        if (owner() != _msgSender()) {
            revert OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(_msgSender());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby disabling any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        if (newOwner == address(0)) {
            revert OwnableInvalidOwner(address(0));
        }
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Internal function without access restriction.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}


interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the value of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the value of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves a `value` amount of tokens from the caller's account to `to`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets a `value` amount of tokens as the allowance of `spender` over the
     * caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves a `value` amount of tokens from `from` to `to` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `value` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}

contract MultiSig is Ownable {
    IERC20 public USDT;
    
    constructor( IERC20 _USDT, address _seller, address _buyer, uint _amount, address _admin1, address _admin2, address _admin3) Ownable(msg.sender) {
        USDT = _USDT;

        deal.seller = _seller;
        deal.buyer = _buyer;
        deal.amount = _amount;
        
        dealAdmin.admin1 = _admin1;
        dealAdmin.admin2 = _admin2;
        dealAdmin.admin3 = _admin3;
        
        dealAdmin.adminFee1 = 1000;
        dealAdmin.adminFee2 = 1000;
        dealAdmin.adminFee3 = 1000;
    }
    
    struct PaymentStatus {
        bool buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid;
        bool sellerExpertFeePaid;
    }

    struct AgreementStatus {
        bool sellerAgreed;
        bool buyerAgreed;
        bool admin1Agreed;
        bool admin2Agreed;
        bool admin3Agreed;
        bool cancelRequested;
        bool disputed;
    }

    struct SettlementProposal {
        uint sellerAmount;
        uint buyerAmount;
        bool submitted;
    }

    SettlementProposal public sellerProposal;
    SettlementProposal public buyerProposal;

    struct SettlementResult {
        uint finalSellerAmount;
        uint finalBuyerAmount;
        bool isDisputed;
    }

    SettlementResult public settlementResult;

    struct Deal {
        address seller;
        address buyer;
        uint amount;
        PaymentStatus paymentStatus;
        AgreementStatus agreementStatus;
        uint score;
        uint adminVotedSuccess;
        bool ended;
    }

    Deal public deal;
    
    struct DealCancel {
        bool admin1;
        bool admin2;
        bool admin3;
        uint adminVoted;
    }
    
    DealCancel public dealCancel;
    
    struct DealAdmin {
        address admin1;
        address admin2;
        address admin3;
        uint adminFee1;
        uint adminFee2;
        uint adminFee3;
    }
    
    DealAdmin public dealAdmin;
    
    function depositDeal() public {
        require(deal.buyer == msg.sender);
        require(!deal.ended);

        uint _fee1 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee1);
        uint _fee2 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee2);
        uint _fee3 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee3);

        uint totalFee = _fee1 + _fee2 + _fee3;
        uint halfFee = totalFee / 2;

        USDT.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), deal.amount + halfFee);
        deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid = true;

        if (deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid && deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid) {
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin1, _fee1); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin2, _fee2); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin3, _fee3); 
        }
    }

    function paySellerExpertFee() public {
        require(deal.seller == msg.sender, "Only the seller can pay the expert fee");
        require(!deal.ended, "Cannot pay the fee after the deal has ended");
        require(!deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid, "Seller expert fee is already paid");

        uint _fee1 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee1);
        uint _fee2 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee2);
        uint _fee3 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee3);

        uint totalFee = _fee1 + _fee2 + _fee3;
        uint halfFee = totalFee / 2;

        USDT.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), halfFee);
        deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid = true;

        if (deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid && deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid) {
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin1, _fee1); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin2, _fee2); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin3, _fee3); 
        }
    }

    function cancelContract() public {
        require(
            (deal.seller == msg.sender || deal.buyer == msg.sender) &&
            (!deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid || !deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid)
        );
        require(!deal.ended);

        if (deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid || deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid) {
            uint _fee1 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee1);
            uint _fee2 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee2);
            uint _fee3 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee3);

            uint totalFee = _fee1 + _fee2 + _fee3;
            uint halfFee = totalFee / 2;

            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin1, halfFee / 3); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin2, halfFee / 3); 
            USDT.transfer(dealAdmin.admin3, halfFee / 3); 

            USDT.transfer(deal.buyer, deal.amount); 
        }
        
        deal.ended = true;
    }
    
    function voteDeal() public { 
        require(!deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested);
        require(!deal.ended);

        if (deal.seller == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed) {
            deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed = true;
            deal.score+= 50;
            
        } else if (deal.buyer == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed) {
            deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed = true;
            deal.score+= 50;
            
        } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin1) {
            require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin1Agreed);
            deal.score += 25;
            deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
            deal.agreementStatus.admin1Agreed = true;
            
        } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin2) {
            require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin2Agreed);
            deal.score += 25;
            deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
            deal.agreementStatus.admin2Agreed = true;
            
        } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin3) {
            require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin3Agreed);
            deal.score += 25;
            deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
            deal.agreementStatus.admin3Agreed = true;
        }

        if (deal.score >= 100) {
            executeDeal();
        }
        
        // if (buyerAmount == 0) {
        //     if (deal.seller == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed) {
        //         deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed = true;
        //         deal.score+= 50;
                
        //     } else if (deal.buyer == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed) {
        //         deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed = true;
        //         deal.score+= 50;
                
        //     } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin1) {
        //         require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin1Agreed);
        //         deal.score += 25;
        //         deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
        //         deal.agreementStatus.admin1Agreed = true;
                
        //     } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin2) {
        //         require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin2Agreed);
        //         deal.score += 25;
        //         deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
        //         deal.agreementStatus.admin2Agreed = true;
                
        //     } else if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin3) {
        //         require(deal.adminVotedSuccess <= 2 && !deal.agreementStatus.admin3Agreed);
        //         deal.score += 25;
        //         deal.adminVotedSuccess++;
        //         deal.agreementStatus.admin3Agreed = true;
        //     }

        //     if (deal.score >= 100) {
        //         executeDeal();
        //     }
        // } else {
        //     if (deal.seller == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed) {
        //         sellerProposals.buyerAmount = buyerAmount;
        //         sellerProposals.sellerAmount = sellerAmount;
        //         sellerProposals.submitted = true;
        //     } else if (deal.buyer == msg.sender && !deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed) {
        //         buyerProposals.buyerAmount = buyerAmount;
        //         buyerProposals.sellerAmount = sellerAmount;
        //         buyerProposals.submitted = true;
        //     }
        //     checkAndSettleDeal();
        // }
    }

    function checkAndSettleDeal() internal {
        if (sellerProposal.submitted && buyerProposal.submitted) {
            if (sellerProposal.sellerAmount == buyerProposal.sellerAmount &&
                sellerProposal.buyerAmount == buyerProposal.buyerAmount) {

                settlementResult.finalBuyerAmount = sellerProposal.buyerAmount;
                settlementResult.finalSellerAmount = sellerProposal.sellerAmount;
                settlementResult.isDisputed = false;

                deal.agreementStatus.sellerAgreed = true;
                deal.score+= 50;

                deal.agreementStatus.buyerAgreed = true;
                deal.score+= 50;

                if (deal.score >= 100) {
                    executeDeal();
                }
                
                deal.ended = true;
            } else {
                settlementResult.finalBuyerAmount = 0;
                settlementResult.finalSellerAmount = 0;
                settlementResult.isDisputed = true;
                
                deal.agreementStatus.disputed = true;
            }
        }
    }
 
    function executeDeal() internal {
        require(
            deal.paymentStatus.buyerDepositAndExpertFeePaid &&
            deal.paymentStatus.sellerExpertFeePaid &&
            deal.score >= 100 &&
            !deal.ended &&
            !deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested
        );
        require(!deal.ended);
        
        USDT.transfer(deal.seller, deal.amount); 
        deal.ended = true;
    }
    
    function cancelDeal() public {
        require(!deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested);
        require(!deal.ended);
        
        require(
            deal.seller == msg.sender ||
            deal.buyer == msg.sender
        );
        
        deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested = true; 
    }
    
    function voteCancelDeal() public {
       require(deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested);
       require(!deal.ended);
       
       if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin1) {
            require(dealCancel.adminVoted <= 2 && !dealCancel.admin1);
            dealCancel.adminVoted++;
            dealCancel.admin1 = true;
            
        } 
        
        if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin2) {
            require(dealCancel.adminVoted <= 2 && !dealCancel.admin2);
            dealCancel.adminVoted++;
            dealCancel.admin2 = true;
            
        } 
        
        if (msg.sender == dealAdmin.admin3) {
            require(dealCancel.adminVoted <= 2 && !dealCancel.admin3);
            dealCancel.adminVoted++;
            dealCancel.admin3 = true;
        }
       
    }
    
    function cancelExecute() public {
        require(deal.agreementStatus.cancelRequested);
        require(!deal.ended);
        require(dealCancel.adminVoted == 2);
        
        USDT.transfer(deal.buyer, deal.amount); 
        deal.ended = true;
    }

    function totalExpertCommissions() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint _fee1 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee1);
        uint _fee2 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee2);
        uint _fee3 = calculate(deal.amount, dealAdmin.adminFee3);

        return _fee1 + _fee2 + _fee3;
    }
    
    // Counting an percentage by basis points
    function calculate(uint256 amount, uint256 bps) public pure returns (uint256) {
        require((amount * bps) >= 10000);
        return amount * bps / 10000;
    }
}

When cancelContract is called, all actions are performed, but deal.ended = true; no, at least when I requested deal as a function to get the data ended in the false response, but other functions can no longer be performed, as if inside the contract ended is still true
UPD:
The problem is due to the fact that two other structures are nested in the Deal, but is it possible to somehow create convenient data structures?
